# How to set DateTime to start/end of the day?

Tags: c#

I want to calculate the start `DateTime` and end `DateTime` of the current week. First of all I created a class holding both information

```
internal class ReportTimeSpan
{
    public DateTime From { get; set; }
    public DateTime To { get; set; }
}
```

After that this is my calculation

```
    public ReportTimeSpan GetTimeSpanForThisWeek()
    {
        int amountOfDays = GetAmountOfWeekDays();
        int currentDayIndex = GetCurrentWeekDayIndex();
        
        DateTime weekStart = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-currentDayIndex);

        int differenceCurrentDayIndexToLastDayIndex = amountOfDays - currentDayIndex;
        DateTime weekEnd = DateTime.Now.AddDays(differenceCurrentDayIndexToLastDayIndex);

        return new ReportTimeSpan()
        {
            From = weekStart,
            To = weekEnd
        };
    }

    private int GetAmountOfWeekDays()
    {
        string[] dayNames = Enum.GetNames(typeof(DayOfWeek));

        return dayNames.Length;
    }

    private int GetCurrentWeekDayIndex()
    {
        DayOfWeek dayOfWeek = DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek;

        return (int)dayOfWeek;
    }
}
```

The date of both values is correct, but the time is wrong.

- The variable `weekStart` should have a time of "00:00:00"
- The variable `weekEnd` should have a time of "23:59:59" (not sure about that)

Are there any methods I can use for this? (I don't want to use external packages)

Comment: `GetAmountOfWeekDays`? Are you expecting the number of days in a week to change in a way that means you won't have to revisit your code in the near future? :D

Comment: So you want to exclude anything that happens *during* the last second of the day? Usually you shouldn't. Better to move to a semi-closed interval, using an *inclusive* start date and an *exclusive* end date (I.e. set `weekEnd` to the midnight at the start of the following day instead and use `<` rather than `<=`). This advice means you never have to worry about the precision of the time element.

Comment: @John exactly :P

Comment: `DateTime.Now` stores the current time, `DateTime.Today` is midnight

Comment: If you just want the time part to become 00:00:00 you can use `DateTime.Date` to get the date part and add `TimeSpan` back with time you need.

Comment: Please be aware that a) DayOfWeek has Sunday as first day of the week (0) and b) using DateTime.Now sooner or later will lead to an unexpected behavior (client's vs server's Now, etc.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I expect you want something like this:

```
weekStart = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-currentDayIndex).Date;
```

As Tim notes, you can simplify this to:

```
weekStart = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-currentDayIndex);
```

`.Date` will remove the time component, so you're just left with the date and a 00:00:00 time. `.Today` will return today's date without a time component.

For `weekEnd`, we should add the number of days in the week to `weekStart`, and then step back 1 tick to take it back into the previous day:

```
weekEnd = weekStart.AddDays(7).AddTicks(-1);
```

You could also use `.AddMilliseconds(-1)`, `.AddSeconds(-1)`, or whatever amount you require to safely be inside the previous day (some databases will have less than tick precision, etc.).

If you have some reason for using `GetAmountOfWeekDays()` then substitute `7` in the above with `GetAmountOfWeekDays()`.

Depending on what you're using this for, you might be better off with an inclusive `weekStart` and an exclusive `nextWeekStart` comparison:

```
weekStart = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-currentDayIndex).Date;
nextWeekStart = weekStart.AddDays(7);

bool isInWeek = someDate >= weekStart && somedate < nextWeekStart;
```

Comment: Why you use `DateTime.Now` at all if you want to truncate the time, use `DateTime.Today`

Answer (score 0):

```
weekStart = weekStart.Date;
weekEnd = weekEnd.AddHours(23).AddMinutes(59).AddSeconds(59).AddMilliseconds(999);
```

OR

```
weekStart = weekStart.Date;
weekEnd = weekEnd.AddHours(24).AddMilliseconds(-1);
```

OR

```
weekStart = weekStart.Date;
weekEnd  = new DateTime(weekEnd .Year, weekEnd .Month, weekEnd .Day, 23, 59, 59);
```